# Disable escape from android app android 4.0+

Tags: android

I am developing application that should start one application and user cannot close that application or leave it. So I need to disable all 3x buttons (Back, Home, Multitask). Disable of back button is easy only override methon onBackPressed(). But how can i disable Home and Multitask. I read that override of Home button is not possible in 4.0+ android so how can i do it? And can i block Multitask button so user cannot escape from Application?

PS: This application will never be released on Android Market so solution can be againts "rules".

Comment: I think you can not do this...

Comment: you can "take control" over the home-button, if you set your ypp as launcher like this:  
`<intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> </intent-filter>`

Answer (score 1):

BackButton

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Suppose you are in activity A you navigate to B and then to C. In Activity C you press back button, activity C is popped from the stack, destroyed and the previous activity which is B is displayed

Suppose you wish to navigate to A from C then you can override back button pressed

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
onBackPressed();
}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(C.this, A.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // clear back stack 
startActivity(myIntent); 
finish(); 
return;
}
```

HomeButton

There is no way to intercept the home button on Android, unless you make your app the home screen. This is for security reasons, so that malicious apps cannot take over your device by overriding all the buttons that can exit. The home button is the one sure shot way to be able to leave any app.

If you want to handle the HOME button, implement a home screen. You cannot disable a home button.

android:launchMode ="standard|singleTop|singleTask |singleInstance"

Check the activity launchmode @ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode for singleInstance. the device can hold only one instance of the activity at a time — only one such task.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide them or dim them. See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility(int)

Comment: home button is hardware button right? So how hide or dim the home button?

Comment: It is good idea but it is not working. You can hide it but when user display keyboard all of them will pop up again.

Comment: @Raghunandan Ducktape the hardware buttons. :<